# Projectile motion with air friction

Tags: projection

I need to find the x and y components of a projectile's position, its velocity at any evaluation point, time of flight, range, and maximum height. I have already made the code for a projectile ignoring air friction, but I am having trouble figuring out how to take air friction into account. I know I need to somehow include these equations

Sum of $Fx = m \times Ax =-k\times Vx$ where $k$ is a constant

Sum of $Fy = m\times Ay =-k \times Vy-mg$

This is my code for the projectile ignoring air friction.

```
h = .01; g = 9.8; x[0] = 0; y[0] = 0; V[0] = 40;
Vx[0] = 40 Cos[40 °];
Vy[0] = 40 Sin[40 °];
Vy[n_] := Vy[n - 1] - g*h;
Vx[n_] := 40 Cos[40 °];
x[n_] := x[n - 1] + 40 Cos[40 °]*h;
y[n_] := y[n - 1] + Vy[n - 1]*h;
t == (V[0]*2*Sin[40 °])/g;
R == (V[0]^2*Sin[2*40 °])/g;
Ymax == Sin[40 °]^2*V[0]^2/(2 g);
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please consider creating an account to take advantage of the many additional features (eg. voting, favorites).

Comment: I suggest you read this [Wolfram Blog article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/09/27/do-computers-dumb-down-math-education/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a physics problem rather than a *Mathematica* problem. But the way you coded is problematic. You shouldn't use induction here, it will only give you integer solutions in your code. Instead, you should solve the equations.

I don't understand your question well, but I think the information I provided is sufficient.

First part, the position and velocity at any time given.

```
DSolve[{m*x''[t] == -k*x'[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 40 Cos[40 °]}, x[t], t]
(*{{x[t] -> (40 E^(-((k t)/m)) (-1 + E^((k t)/m)) m Cos[40 °])/k}}*)

D[x[t] /. Flatten@%, t] // FullSimplify
(*40 E^(-((k t)/m)) Cos[40 °]*)

DSolve[{m*y''[t] == -k*y'[t] - mg, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 40 Sin[40 °]}, y[t], t]
(*{{y[t] -> -((E^(-((k t)/m)) (m mg - E^((k t)/m) m mg + E^((k t)/m) k mg t + 
   40 k m Sin[40 °] - 40 E^((k t)/m) k m Sin[40 °]))/k^2)}}*)

D[y[t] /. Flatten@%, t] // FullSimplify
(*(-mg + E^(-((k t)/m)) (mg + 40 k Sin[40 °]))/k*)

x[t_]:= (40 E^(-((k t)/m)) (-1 + E^((k t)/m)) m Cos[40 °])/k;
Vx[t_]:= 40 E^(-((k t)/m)) Cos[40 °];
y[t_]:=(E^(-((k t)/m)) (-E^(((k t)/m))k mg t + (-1 + E^((k t)/m)) m (mg + 
  40 k Sin[40 °])))/k^2
Vy[t_]:=(-mg + E^(-((k t)/m)) (mg + 40 k Sin[40 °]))/k
R[t_]:=Sqrt[x[t]^2+y[t]^2]
Ymax[t_]:=(m (-mg Log[1 + (40 k Sin[40 °])/mg] + 40 k Sin[40 °]))/k^2
```

Second, the position and velocity at any position `x=s`

```
Solve[x[t] == s, t]
(*{{t -> ConditionalExpression[(m (2 I π C[1] + 
   Log[(40 m Cos[40 °])/(-k s + 
     40 m Cos[40 °])]))/k, C[1] ∈ Integers]}}*)
```

Simply take `C[1]=0` then plug it into `y[t]`, you will get

```
y[s_]:=(mg (-40 m Log[1 + (k s)/(-k s + 40 m Cos[40 °])] + 
k s Sec[40 °]))/(40 k^2) + s Tan[40 °]
```

for `y=h`, you can follow the similar steps.

Answer (score 1):

Define constants

```
m = 1; g = 9.8; k = .1;
```

Define initial conditions

```
vZero = 40;
θzero = 40 Degree;
init = {
  Thread[{rx[0], ry[0]} == {0, 0}],
  Thread[{vx[0], vy[0]} == {vZero Cos[θzero], vZero Sin[θzero]}]
  }
```

Define some force [`Functions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

```
fGrav[r_List] := {0 , -m g } r
fWind[v_List] := -k v
```

Solve the differential equations with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
soln = DSolve[
   Flatten@{
     Thread[
      m {rx''[t], ry''[t]} == 
       fGrav@ {rx[t], ry[t]} + fWind@ {vx[t], vy[t]}],
     Thread[{vx[t], vy[t]} == {rx'[t], ry'[t]}],
     init
     },
   {rx[t], ry[t], vx[t], vy[t]},
   t
   ];
```

Then plot them with [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) if you want to visualize the trajectory

```
ParametricPlot[Flatten@({rx[t], ry[t]} /. soln), {t, 0, 2},  AxesLabel -> {"rx", "ry"}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Remember, of course, that this is a mathematical solution. Normal ballistic objects tend not to go underground so exuberantly.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to model a projectile launched into a tangible atmosphere. So drag as well a wind must be considered. Hitting the ground could be modeled as a discontinuity in the drag, with soil being considered a very high drag  medium :-)

Comment: That would be a rather interesting model. I assumed here that the OP wasn't quite clear what they wanted and had just been handed a poor model of "atmospheric drag" in their problem; the fact that the OP posted a [rather similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77882/projectile-motion-in-mathematica-using-eulers-method), to which you provided a very nice answer, only decreased the weakness of my suspicion. A perusal of the excellent blog entry you posted above is well placed here.